# Curl outputs variable name instead of its contents

Tags: php, curl

Below is my code, after searching and working all night, I finally figured how to make it send an sms. The problem is that I can't leave spaces in the body message and it does not display the value of `$smsmessage`.

```
extract($_POST);

$smsmessage1 = "This is the sms that will be sent";
$smsmessage = urlencode($smsmessage1);

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://www.mysmsgateway.com/bulksms/bulksms.php?username=myemail@domain.com&password=123456789&message=$smsmessage&mobile=2348035081907&sender=Boss';
$fields = array();

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

The above codes sends the message but will output `$smsmessage` instead of fetching the value of `$smsmessage` from above.

Comment: Please use code block to put your code... you will not get reply with such a confusing code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using single quotes for specifying `$url`, which means the `$smsmessage` won't be interpreted.

You'll need to use double quotes instead:

```
$url = "http://www.mysmsgateway.com/bulksms/bulksms.php?username=myemail@domain.com&password=123456789&message=$smsmessage&mobile=2348035081907&sender=Boss";
```

For more information about the difference between the two, see [PHP: Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) from the PHP manual.

Comment: You guys are God sent, this is gonna be my community. Thanks all... finally, everything is working fine. u've made my day.

Comment: @Naira4Dollar: Happy to help. Remember to accept an answer if your problem is solved. :)

Comment: @Naira4Dollar: You click the checkmark on the left of the answer you like the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

Variables placed inside single quote are not evaluated in php, place them in double quote. like

```
//set POST variables 
$url = "http://www.mysmsgateway.com/bulksms/bulksms.php?username=myemail@domain.com&password=123456789&message=$smsmessage&mobile=2348035081907&sender=Boss"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes instead of double quotes. Only double quotes will parse variables for you. So instead of typing:

```
$url = 'http://www.mysmsgateway.com/bulksms/bulksms.php?username=myemail@domain.com&password=123456789&message=$smsmessage&mobile=2348035081907&sender=Boss';
```

Try using double quotes and type:

```
$url = "http://www.mysmsgateway.com/bulksms/bulksms.php?username=myemail@domain.com&password=123456789&message=$smsmessage&mobile=2348035081907&sender=Boss";
```

Comment: You guys are God sent, this is gonna be my community. Thanks all... finally, everything is working fine. u've made my day.